# QGIS digitisng : fid error - field has highlight & red cross

Tags: qgis

QGIS version  3.20.1-Odense on Linux Mint 20.1.
I created a couple of shapefile layers by exporting the tables from a geopackage I'd created in a different project.  I added features to these (points and polylines) a few days ago, with no problems.
I've come back to this project to finish it & get the error condition shown in the screenshot.
I've searched online but found nothing close.  Have tried exporting to new shapefiles and also laundering via KML, but problem still persists.  Any ideas how to resolve?

[image]

Comment: did you try putting a value in `fid`?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. I added rownumber.  Interestingly, there is other stuff going on - I added a few points in a new shapefile, then pasted them into a copy of the problem layer and it accepted them.  However, it's converting the digit "1" into "-9223372036854775808" and won't let me delete it or retype NULL.  Presumably all stemming from being a gpkg table?

Comment: more likely to do with ShapeFiles being so old and obsolete :-( I'm not clear on why you created shapefiles from a geopackage?

Comment: Widely in use and obsolete? It is obsolete when it isn't used.  Just because a tech elite have moved on doesn't make it so - it may be correct to say that they are obsolescent though. I'm not saying we shouldn't move on from them, but the (end user) base of the pyramid is wide & change will be slow.  I use .shp because my clients work with .shp.  They're a simple tool & are widely accepted & you don't need to know anything about databases to use them.  In nearly 25 years of working with .shp, I've never encountered this, so to me I'd think the .gpkg origin could be something to do with it.

Comment: the problem is that shapefiles don['t have fids, just row numbers and all sorts of things can screw them up, your best bet is to delete the corrupted one and start again,